# why all browser shows the href links in blue color?

Tags: html

Why the h ref link are shown in blue colour default?
Any special reason for the colour?
why all browsers follow this standard ?[link shown in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrdHL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red and green are the colours most affected by colour-vision deficiency.  Almost no one has a blue deficiency. Accordingly, nearly everyone can see blue, or, more accurately, almost everyone can distinguish blue as a colour different from others. It was pure good luck that the default colour of hyperlinks is blue with underlining.